# Why WordPress' server doesn't need to be reloaded after update?

Tags: python, php, flask, wsgi

When I change my Flask application, I have to restart my WSGI server to see the changes. My question is how WordPress doesn't need to be reloaded after each update or installing a new plugin? Is it possible to have an update button in my Flask app that changes my app's files without having to reload the server after the update?

Comment: _"My question is how WordPress doesn't need to be reloaded after each update or installing a new plugin?"_ - because PHP code gets interpreted on-the-fly (usually - if there is no Opcode cache or similar involved.)